# How to connect mysql to Node JS?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have installed mysql on my computer though it showed some packages may not be installed (during installation) but its showing unexpected erros when I'm trying to execute with Node JS.

I have tried both global and local method of installing mysql using 'npm' and tried in every directory but still my code is not working properly .

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost",
user: "yourusername",
password: "yourpassword",
database: "mydb"
  });

con.connect(function(err) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log("Connected!");
 var sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES ?";
 var values = [
['John', 'Highway 71'],
['Peter', 'Lowstreet 4'],
['Amy', 'Apple st 652'],
['Hannah', 'Mountain 21'],
['Michael', 'Valley 345'],
['Sandy', 'Ocean blvd 2'],
['Betty', 'Green Grass 1'],
['Richard', 'Sky st 331'],
['Susan', 'One way 98'],
['Vicky', 'Yellow Garden 2'],
['Ben', 'Park Lane 38'],
['William', 'Central st 954'],
['Chuck', 'Main Road 989'],
['Viola', 'Sideway 1633']
  ];
con.query(sql, [values], function (err, result) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
 });
 });
```

I have installed properly everything from Node to Mysql and it is showing error in try catch block .Please suggest something

Comment: That code is working correctly on my environment, I see 14 records inserted. So I'd try connecting via the command line mysql app and see if you can connect.

Comment: "it is showing error". Which are ?

Comment: To be able to debug the issue, maybe consider adding; connection.connect(function(err) {
  console.log(err.code); // 'ECONNREFUSED'
  console.log(err.fatal); // true
});

Comment: C:\Users\luckyy\Desktop\Node JS\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:80
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^
Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\luckyy\Desktop\Node JS\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket 
Please Note : I am running it in normal cmd of windows and Im running in Node JS directory ..please help

Answer (score 0):

mysql and node js connection and configuration

`reference url:` [Access MySQL server in private ec2 instance in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60504692/access-mysql-server-in-private-ec2-instance-in-nodejs/60633941#60633941)