# Access MySQL server in private ec2 instance in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS and Node js. I want to query a MySQL server in a private ec2 instance in a testing project which I am building using Node js. How should I go about it?
Thanks

EDIT: I want to access it through my local computer. The way I came up with was:

1. Start a terminal from node js - don't know which method would be best
2. Use the terminal to login into public ec2
3. connect to private ec2 through public instance
4. launch the MySQL client through private instance and query it.

I wanted to know if there is a better way to do this. And any advice on how to achieve the same

Comment: Need to read up about VPC, private subnets, Internet gateways, NAT gateways, VPC interface endpoints, security groups, nacles, and more. AWS docs is good place to start.

Comment: Are you going to query the MySQL from outside (internet) or from another EC2 instance in the same VPC? Because that point is important to either use a NAT Gateway or any other approach

Answer (score 2):

1. install the package: **jm-ez-mysql**

   **npm install jm-ez-mysql --save**

   use this document url: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jm-ez-mysql
2. configuration and connection databse
   database.js file

   const My = require('jm-ez-mysql');

   ```
   // Init DB Connection
   const connection = My.init({
     host: process.env.DBHOST,
     user: process.env.DBUSER,
     password: process.env.DBPASSWORD,
     database: process.env.DATABASE,
     dateStrings: true,
     charset: 'utf8mb4',
     timezone: 'utc',
     multipleStatements: true,
     connectTimeout: 100 * 60 * 1000,
     acquireTimeout: 100 * 60 * 1000,
     timeout: 100 * 60 * 1000,
   });

   module.exports = {
     connection,
   };
   ```

In express js project to configuration database

```
/config
  /database.js
/server.js
/.env

const http = require('http');
const app = require('express')();
require('./config/database.js');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(process.env.ServerPort, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  logger.info(`Express server listening on port ${process.env.ServerPort}`);
});
```

3. server.js file

   const My = require('jm-ez-mysql');

   My.first("psu_project", ["id"], "1=1 ").then(function (r) 
   {
       console.log(r);
   });

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the package: mysql

   **npm install -save mysql**
2. Connect MySQL to the server.

Example:

```
const mysqlConnection = require('mysql').createConnection;

mysqlConnection = mysqlConnection({
        host: HOST,
        user: DB_USER,
        password: DB_PASSWORD,
        database: DB_NAME,
      });
mysqlConnection.connect();

mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM table_name');
```

NOTE: query() is an asynchronous function.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately this is not what i was looking for. Please refer to the addition.